# List freqüents with nuls values

Tags: mysql, null, frequency

I have a DB in Mysql where I want to count how many type of Players has a team. My problem is that I want to show all the type of players, even if the team does not have that kind of player.
Let me show you the data Tables:

```
INSERT INTO typePlayer (id_typeplayer,type_player,id_race) VALUES
(57,"zombi",15),
(58,"necrofago",15),
(59,"tumulario",15),
(60,"Hobre Lobo",15),
(61,"Golem de Carne",15);

INSERT INTO teams (id_team, id_race) VALUES 
(7,15);

INSERT INTO Players (id_player, id_typeplayer, id_team) VALUES
(1,60,7),
(2,60,7),
(3,58,7),
(4,58,7),
(5,59,7),
(6,59,7),
(7,57,7),
(8,57,7),
(9,57,7),
(10,57,7),
(11,57,7);
```

I'd love to have a query that gives me this:

```
57,zombi,5
58,necrofago,2
59,tumulario,2
60,Hombre Lobo,2
61,Golem de Carne,0
```

My problem is that I cannot show the last row (where count is null, because the team has no player of that type)
I've tried this, with bad result:

```
SELECT tP.id_typeplayer,
       count(p.id_typeplayer) cant,
       p.id_team
FROM players p
JOIN typePlayer tP ON(tP.id_typeplayer=p.id_typeplayer)
WHERE (p.status='En activo'
       OR p.status='Lesionado')
  AND p.independiente='No'
  AND p.zombificado='No'
  AND p.id_team=7
  AND tP.id_race=15
GROUP BY tP.id_typeplayer HAVING cant>=0
```

I'll thank any help

Comment: WHY ALL CAPS IN TITLE?

Comment: can u make [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? so it is easier to understand.

Comment: Why `57,zombi,4`? Should it be `57,zombi,5` because there are 5 players of that type?

Comment: I'm a newbie here.  I do not know  what sqlfiddle is

Comment: Anonymous thank you.  I've already  edited that error

Comment: Not sure if this'll work but you can try `select tp.id_typeplayer,tp.type_player,count(*) from typePlayer tp left join players p on tp.id_typeplayer=p.id_typeplayer group by tp.id_typeplayer;`

Comment: Need to add one more column to the group by expression `group by tp.id_typeplayer, tp.type_player)`

Comment: I'll  check  it later, thanks  anyway

Comment: It doesn't work that wayanonymous, cos it shows you 1 Golem de Carne, besides you must count p.id_team=7, cos it might be that there were more id_typeplayers from other teams.  :( Is it possible to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL, what you need is to include all `typePlayer` tuples even if there are no players of that type. That would be a left join if `typePlayer` table is on the left hand side or a right join if `typePlayer` table is on the right hand side.

I actually went to the link you provided in sqlfiddle. Your `typePlayer` table is on the right, so I changed it to a right join. The resultant SQL is as follows

```
SELECT tP.id_typeplayer,tp.type_player,
   sum(if(p.id_team is null, 0,1)) cant,
   p.id_team
FROM players p
RIGHT JOIN typePlayer tP ON(tP.id_typeplayer=p.id_typeplayer)
GROUP BY tP.id_typeplayer
```

The other thing you mentioned in your comment is to have only `id_team=7` which I think you just need to filter out in a where clause like this.

```
SELECT tP.id_typeplayer,tp.type_player,
   sum(if(p.id_team is null, 0,1)) cant,
   p.id_team
FROM players p
RIGHT JOIN typePlayer tP ON(tP.id_typeplayer=p.id_typeplayer)
WHERE p.id_team=7 or p.id_team is null    
GROUP BY tP.id_typeplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a LEFT JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN, and leave the HAVING clause out

```
SELECT tP.id_typeplayer,
   count(p.id_typeplayer) cant,
   p.id_team
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN typePlayer tP ON(tP.id_typeplayer=p.id_typeplayer)
WHERE (p.status='En activo'
    OR p.status='Lesionado')
    AND p.independiente='No'
    AND p.zombificado='No'
    AND p.id_team=7
    AND tP.id_race=15
GROUP BY tP.id_typeplayer
```

Try this query, we introduce the teams table:

```
SELECT
    tp.type_player,
    p.team_id,
    COUNT(p.id_typeplayer)
FROM
    teams t
JOIN
    typePlayers tp
    ON t.id_race = tp.id_race
LEFT JOIN
    players p
    ON p.id_team = t.id_team
    AND tp.id_type_player = p.id_type_player
    AND (p.status='En activo' OR p.status='Lesionado')
    AND p.independiente='No'
    AND p.zombificado='No'
    AND p.id_team=7
WHERE
    t.race_id = 15      
GROUP BY
    tp.type_player, p.team_id
```

The where conditions are moved to the (left) join conditions

Comment: I put all the code in fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95ef30/1/0) And it does not work yet. The (61,Golem de Carne,0) is not there. ANY HELP??

Comment: I suggested an edit, because some significant data is missing. The insert query for players will result in an error